# Why is ggplot drawing straight lines intermittently along my time series geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with two geom_lines that plot a rolling 7-day sum of data for 2019 and 2020, on the x axis is a numeric variable where I have removed the year from date to give a day/month (101, 102 all the way to 1231).

Something, probably the date, is causing the ggplot to draw straight lines over ~70 days. Any ideas how I can plot all the points without skipping like this?

Attached is a picture of the ggplot and Excel where it plots perfectly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
options(scipen=1000000) 

plot_a <- ggplot(data = Total_Arrivals) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = SevenDaySum2019, group ='Date'), colour= company_colour[3]) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = SevenDaySum2020, group ='Date'), colour= company_colour[2]) +
  theme_company

ggplotly(plot_a)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try after removing `group ='Date'` throughout

Comment: Hi Phil. Removing that part still produces the staggered ggplot as above

Comment: Using a full date (2020-12-01) on the x-axis works fine but as I am plotting 2019 and 2020 it doesn't look as good as if I could have a date minus the year on the X. I realise this is unlikely but struggling to use any numeric variable on the x-axis

Comment: Can you use `dput(Total_Arrivals)` and include the output in your question, so that it can be reproduced?